# "can't extract token and secret invalid consumer scribe "

Tags: java, android, scribe

I'm an Italian student and I'm trying to create an IssueTracker Android for Bitbucket.

I'm using scribe and but I'm blocked on 1st step (retrieve request token)

I've created my BitbucketApi class

```
@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    return "https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/oauth/access_token";
}

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken) {
    return "https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=" +   requestToken.getToken();
}

@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    return "https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/oauth/request_token";
}
```

and this is the portion code of my authentication flow

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                            .provider(BitbucketApi.class)
                            .apiKey(MY_API_KEY)
                            .apiSecret(MY_API_SECRET)
                            .build();
requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
```

but I receive always that exception after this method:

```
authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
```

because requestToken is null

Could someone help me please?

Comment: are you sure `getRequestToken` does not fail with some sort of exception/message/... ?

Comment: Sorry I'cant create code-block in this comment However in my 'doInBackground' I've this try-catch block. try { requestToken = service.getRequestToken(); authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken); Log.w("req_tkn", requestToken.toString()); Log.w("auth_url", authUrl); } catch (Exception e) { Log.d("MSG", e.getMessage()); } And the MSG = Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'invalid consumer'

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve the issue? When try to get request token, the server always return 400 (Could not verify OAuth request.)

I checked the parameter closely, and make sure server's time is correct.. still can't solve it.

[UPDATED] Finally, I got the reason. I put a space before the request_Url by mistake; after I remove the space, it works well.

```
@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    return "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token";
}
```